# List and download files in a folder in a blob with blob level SAS token

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-lake-gen2

I got a SAS token which was created for a specific folder on my Azure Datalake Gen2. The goal is, to download the folder with all its contents.

I understand, that I can create a DataLakeServiceClient, a FileSystemClient, or a DataLakeDirectoryClient as follows:

```
# configuration
url = 'https://my-account.blob.core.windows.net'
sas_token = '<sas-token>'
file_system_name =  'file_system_1'
subfolder_path = 'subfolder_1'

# service client
data_lake_service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url=url, credential=sas_token)

# directory client and file system client
file_system_client = data_lake_service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system=file_system_name)
data_lake_directory_client = data_lake_service_client.get_directory_client(file_system=file_system_name, directory=subfolder_path)
```

Now to download specific files, I need to know what files exist:

- Unfortunately, the `DataLakeDirectoryClient` does not have a function to get all paths of the files inside that directory.
- On the other hand, the `FileSystemClient` has that function but is searching on the file system level, where my SAS token does not have access.

How do I list and download all files in my directory?

Comment: It looks like the underlying API does not support what you want so its probably not possible: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

In Portal created SAS for subfolder2 and below are files in that folder:

[image]

**`Code`** which worked for me :

```
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient
import os

url1 = "https://accountname.dfs.core.windows.net"
sas = "sp=racwdlmeop&st=2023-08-30T10:46:22Z&se=2023-08-30T18:6:2Z&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&sr=d&sig=kCkP25wyg%2A5"
subfolderpath="folder2/subfolder2"
data_lake_service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url=url1, credential=sas)
containername="rithwik"

fsc = data_lake_service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system=containername)

portalfolder = [path.name for path in fsc.get_paths(path=subfolderpath)]

for fp in portalfolder:
    fct = fsc.get_file_client(file_path=fp)
    retrievedfile = fct.download_file()
    print(retrievedfile)
    localSaving = os.path.join(r'C:\Users\Desktop\New folder', fp)
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(localSaving), exist_ok=True)
    with open(localSaving, "wb") as f:
        f.write(retrievedfile.readall())
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

Downloaded Locally:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, the issue that the FileSystemClient could not read the paths was actually, that my base URL was wrong. 
`https://my-account.blob.core.windows.net` should be `https://my-account.dfs.core.windows.net`

Comment: Glad, it solved your problem!

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're experiencing stems from the client attempting to scan the root level, where your provided SAS token lacks permission.

Here's a how I'd address this:

1. **Using the Correct Client**: Given the authentication restrictions, if you can't utilize `FileSystemClient`, consider working directly with the `DataLakeDirectoryClient` for the subfolder. This is contingent on the SAS token granting access to that particular subfolder.
2. **Listing Directly from DirectoryClient**: You can leverage the DataLakeDirectoryClient to directly list paths. This approach should be effective, assuming your SAS token grants the correct permissions for the `subfolder_path`. If not, you might need to tweak the SAS token's permissions.
3. **Downloading the Files**: With the paths in hand, the subsequent process for file downloading remains consistent.

code snippet:

**Listing Files using DataLakeDirectoryClient**:

```py
paths = data_lake_directory_client.list_paths(upn=True)
file_paths = [path.name for path in paths if not path.is_directory]
```

**Downloading the Files**:

```py
import os
destination_folder = "path_to_save_files"

for file_path in file_paths:
    file_client = data_lake_directory_client.get_file_client(file_path)
    dest_path = os.path.join(destination_folder, os.path.basename(file_path))
    
    with open(dest_path, "wb") as f:
        data_stream = file_client.download_file()
        f.write(data_stream.readall())
```

If you encounter authentication issues with the FileSystemClient due to the SAS token's scope, maybe give the DataLakeDirectoryClient a shot? And, you know, double-checking the permissions on your SAS token could be helpful. Just throwing out some ideas! Let me know if anything still doesn't work out.

Comment: The syntax for the first line does not exist. I assume you wanted to to `paths = file_system_client.get_paths(path=subfolder_path)`
But this gives me an authentication error, as my SAS token only has access under `subfolder_path` but the scan is done on the root level.